# TestNG execution order for test groups

Tags: java, testing, testng

Say I have the following XML:

```
<suite name="MATS">
    <test name="mats_test">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="mats" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <packages>
        <package name="com.tests" />
    </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And each test class in the `com.tests` package has only one test method with varying group annotations. Will the `beforeClass()` and `afterClass()` methods of classes not in the "mats" group be executed?

Answer (score 1):

Before/After methods not in the specified group(s) will not run unless they set `alwaysRun` to `true`.

> `alwaysRun`
>
> For before methods (beforeSuite, beforeTest, beforeTestClass and
>   beforeTestMethod, but not beforeGroups): If set to true, this
>   configuration method will be run regardless of what groups it belongs
>   to.
>
> For after methods (afterSuite, afterClass, ...): If set to true, this
>   configuration method will be run even if one or more methods invoked
>   previously failed or was skipped.

e.g. Given the following classes:

```
public class AMatsTest {
    @BeforeSuite(groups = {"mats"})
    public void beforeSuite() {}
}

public class NotAMatsTest {
    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {}
}

@Test(groups = {"mats"})
public class AnotherMatsTest {
    @BeforeSuite public void beforeSuite() {}
}

public class AlwaysTest {
    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeSuite() {}
}
```

`AMatsTest.beforeSuite()`, `AnotherMatsTest.beforeSuite()`, and `AlwaysTest.beforeSuite()` will be executed.
`NotAMatsTest.beforeSuite()` will not be executed.